# site question | Dates of posts, why no years?

Tags: ssd, request

Just wondering why SSD doesn't show the year that a question or answer was posted.
Sometimes I search, see the date for the replies and have no idea if its from this year or last year.
Is it better to bump a dead discussion or start a new one?

I think this info should be in the FAQ

Thanks
~Jon~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the year only shows when it is not this year. In other words, your question currently says "asked 9 mins ago". Tomorrow it'll say "asked yesterday", in three months it'll say "asked Oct 5th" and next year it'll say "asked Oct 5th 2011".

[Check this link](https://sound.stackexchange.com/search?q=Best+entry-level+portable+recorder) and you'll see the first question in the list is dated 2010, and the rest just with the month (as they were asked this year).

At least, that's how I think it works..

Comment: Thanks. That was the first time I'd seen a year on a post, I think I'd rather see the year for anything past a month ago.